# MES system for manufacturing plant

Tags: python, database, windows, plc, data-acquisition

I am working on creating an app that access PLC to gather data and then display it on the screen with the option of viewing the data as an interactive graph. There has been some work done in python that collects data, store them in excel and at the end process the data to get some meaning full data points and visualization using matplotlib.

They have used tkinter to be the interface to get data and display the current values on 2 screens, I have plans to update the program to store the data in a database and query them as per the needs using python.

What would be the ideal GUI package and the data visualization tools I can use to make the app interactive and easy to use on a PC?

As for as why I chose python, I feel comfortable using python.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: [Anvil](https://anvil.works/) might be a suitable Python framework?

Comment: Thanks, I saw the website does have a dashboard example similar to what I had in mind to show the data I want. I will definitely try it out.

Comment: check out https://pyscript.net/. just use a browser for display/presentation. use Windows PC for work/processing. Use iOS/MACOS/Android Platform for UI, content display

Answer (score 0):

It's not a free solution, but you might want to look at Ignition [[link]](https://inductiveautomation.com/)

I have been using it for several years now and it has some great depth and flexibility for capturing data from most brands of PLCs and then displaying the data on a HMI, webpage, uploading to SQL, and so on.
The scripting language is jython, so you should feel very comfortable there. You can also try if for free for two-hours at a time.  Then reset the trial as many times as you like.